# PHP cookie not setting in browser

Tags: php, cookies

I am building a website and am setting a cookie in a php page for when they log in. For some reason that cookie is not setting and I cannot figure out why.

```
    $temp = $DB->getInstance()->Read('Users',null,array('Conditions' => array('name'=>$_POST['user']), 'Selectors' => array('id', 'type')));
    setcookie('authtoken',$temp[0]['id']."-" . $_POST['user'] . "-" . $temp[0]['type'], time()+1800);
```

When I go to chromes console, I do not see the cookie appear

thanks

Comment: Any output before you set the cookie? That won't work.

Comment: what do you mean by output?
I do a die(json_encode(array("Failed" => "Not Authenticated"))); in an if statement